# Как лучше проектировать интерфейс репозитория?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, архитектура, dao, репозиторий

В общем о своем больном) Посоветуйте пожалуйста, на какие подходы стоит обратить внимание.

Суть вопроса: вот есть условно три таблицы в БД.

```
Order:
   Id
   Number
   Date

OrderItem:
   Id
   OrderId
   ProductId
   Quantity

OrderItemFact:
   Id
   OrderItemId
   Quantity
   Date
   StockId
```

Для них существует три класса для маппинга:

```
public class OrderDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
public class OrderItemDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}
public class OrderItemFactDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderItemId { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int StockId { get; set; }
}
```

Так же существуют классы для предметной области какие то такие:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; }
    public List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; set; }
}
public class OrderItem
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public int OrderId { get; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public OrderItemFact Fact { get; set; }
}
public class OrderItemFact
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public int OrderItemId { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; }
    public int StockId { get; set; }
}
```

Далее есть интерфейс репозитория для агрегата сущностей заказа что-то навроде:

```
public interface IOrderRepository
{
    Order GetById(int id);
    Order GetByNumber(string number);
    Order Create();
    void Update(Order order);
    void Delete(Order order);
    List<Order> GetAll();
}
```

Ну и условно существует его 3 реализации где-то на инфраструктурном слое, одна на ADO, другая на Dapper, третья на EntityFramework

Сначала все ок, но со временем будут появляться новые требования, например выборка по дате, далее выборка по дате факта, далее например захотят вытащить что нибудь экзотичное вроде "показать те заказы, где все поступления по ним пришли не позднее недели с момента отправки и например по какому то конкретному продукту"

Понятно, что тащить все в память, а потом фильтровать коллекцию - избыточно с точки зрения ресурсов. Плодить новые методы в интерфейсах и реализациях не хочется на каждый такой запрос.

Первое что приходит в голову - добавить в интерфейс что-то такое

```
List<Order> GetByParameters(DateTime date1, DateTime date2, int productId ....);
```

Но это как-то совсем не очень далее, в голову приходит передавать в GetByParameters массив объектов ключ-условие-значение:

```
List<Order> GetByParameters(List<Parameter> parameters)
```

Но я не уверен, что это правильный подход.

В общем, наверное для этого существуют какие-то хорошие решения, хотелось бы понять как это лучше организовать, м.б. есть какие-то статьи почитать или еще что-то. Буду признателен за помощь :)

Comment: Можно попробовать через LINQ Expression'ы. Т.е получаете такое выражение на вход, анализируете это дерево и строите динамически логику.

Comment: @Александр Кубит вы можете наружу пробрасывать IQueryable, оборачивая выборки в функции, которые возвращаются IQueryable. Правда придется следить, чтобы N+1 не было.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Основной подход — это для каждого сценария делать один метод репозитория. Иногда, если сценарии близки, можно чуть обобщить метод, но в целом *апологеты чистого кода* рекомендуют не использовать булевы параметры или null-параметры. См. Роберт Мартин "Чистый код", разделы Аргументы-флаги (стр. 66), Не передавайте null (стр. 139).

Второе соображение — опираться на принцип [YAGNI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI) во время разработки. Не усложнять проект заранее.

> Сначала все ок, но со временем будут появляться новые требования, например выборка по дате, далее выборка по дате факта, далее например захотят вытащить что нибудь экзотичное вроде "показать те заказы, где все поступления по ним пришли не позднее недели с момента отправки и например по какому то конкретному продукту"

Подход, принятый в Agile — есть собаку по частям. Сложные сценарии могут появиться, а могут не появиться. Для начала реализуем простые.

Но если действительно есть сценарии, в которых нужно сформировать сложный запрос, можно опираться на паттерн *объект запроса*.

*Объект запроса* содержит все значимые параметры, которые мы учитываем при формировании SQL. Предположим, у нас есть задача показать всех пользователей, имя которых начинается с подстроки, зарегистрированных в открытом интервале времени.

```
class QueryObject
{
    public string StartOfName { get; set; }

    public DateTime? Begin { get; set; }

    public DateTime? End { get; set; }
}
```

Метод репозитория может быть описан так:

```
interface IUserRepository
{
    User[] ReadAllByQuery(QueryObject query, int offset, int count);
}
```

Реализация в EF:

```
public User[] ReadAllByQuery(QueryObject query, int offset, int count)
{
    var users = dbContext.Users;

    if (query.StartOfName != null && query.StartOfName.Length > 3)
        users = users.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(query.StartOfName);

    if (query.Begin != null)
        users = users.Where(x => x.CreatedAt >= query.Begin.Value);

    if (query.End != null)
        users = users.Where(x => x.CreatedAt < query.End.Value);

    return users.Select(x => new User(x))
                .ToArray();
}
```

Использование `IQueryable` — штука неоднозначная. Если в предметную область переносятся DTO-объекты EF, это анти-паттерн *Анемичный объект*. DTO не имеют поведения, а объекты предметной области имеют, и это поведение с неизбежностью придётся выносить куда-нибудь, например, в классы-службы, нарушая принцип инкапсуляции.

Мой выбор — явный метод на каждый сценарий использования. Код получается простым, быстро разрабатывается и быстро расширяется.

**UPDATE**

На вопрос из комментария решил ответить в статье. Где хранить объекты запросов?

Поскольку объект запроса передаётся в репозиторий в качестве параметра, он должен быть описан там же, где и интерфейс репозитория, то есть в предметной области. Преимуществом объекта-запроса является то, что в нём нет поведения и все его поля имеют простые типы. Фактически, это Data Transfer Object, его можно выносить наружу, например, делать доступным в сборке REST API.

Comment: Спасибо, все достаточно понятно, а где бы рекомендовали хранить объекты запросов? Предположу, что они должны быть максимально общими для разного рода запросов и не должны относиться к доменным сущностям или к реализациям репозиториев.

Comment: @АлександрКубит, дописал статью (после слова **UPDATE**), постарался ответить на вопрос комментария.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутые ответы.

Comment: Знаю, что наверное стоило бы создать новый вопрос, но все же при подобном построении приложения, стоит ли создавать дополнительный слой DTO объектов для уровня представления и дополнительный конструктор у сущности предметной области? Просто логично предположить, что если у нас существует один конструктор для объекта предметной области, в который передается DTO объект, то и в случае создания нового объекта предметной области с уровня представления,  для передачи его в метод Save репозитория, придется сформировать DTO объект на уровне представления что бы создать сам объект предметной области.

Comment: @АлександрКубит, если учитывать зависимости, то сущность не должна знать о моделях представления. Они про неё знают, она центр приложения, а сама сущность практически ничего не знает о внешнем мире за пределами предметной области. Операция `Save`, если её делать через *Единицу Работы* (Unit of Work), подразумевает, что сначала сущность загружается из базы, потом вы меняете у неё свойства, и она помечается, как изменённая, затем вызываете метод `Save()` у *Единицы работы* и она сохраняет все сущности, помеченные как новые и изменённые, и удаляет помеченные как удалённые.

Comment: Я немного не корректно выразился. Сущности еще нет в БД, мы еще только формируем данные на уровне представления, с целью отправить например в экшен контроллера (json через ajax) чтобы там сформировать объект предметной области и сохранить в БД. Т.к. у объекта предметной области один конструктор, который принимает DTO объект, то для создания этого объекта нам придется сформировать DTO объект. Т.е. по сути для простоты мы должны принимать в экшене в качестве параметра DTO объект. Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @АлександрКубит, часто репозиторий реализует CRUD, соответственно и Create — создание объекта — становится задачей репозитория. Метод `Create` получает в параметрах необходимые поля, создаёт DTO, сохраняет в базе, затем на основании этого DTO создаёт сущность предметной области, и возвращает её. Это один из сценариев, но один из основных. Его часто применяют. Ну а уровень представления видит уровень предметной области, и, соответственно, интерфейс репозитория. Может вызывать `Create`, подставляя данные из своей модели.

Comment: Спасибо, я думал об этом, и мне это нравится, но что делать, если объект сложный и с уровня представления поступает много данных, было бы логично соединить их в каком нибудь типе, но тогда придется объявлять этот тип на уровне предметной области, чтобы засунуть в интерфейс репозитория, я условно и назвал этот тип "DTO для уровня представления". Просто скажем если в интерфейсе у метода Create(...) указано 10 и более параметров, появляется желание все эти параметры запихать в какой то тип.

Comment: @АлександрКубит. Понял. Этот тип тоже относится к предметной области, не к представлению. По сути это конечно DTO, но в DDD такому типу выделена отдельная роль — Value Object (объект-значение). Это например, координаты (два дробных числа), цвета (три целых числа 0..255) и так далее. Иногда такой тип может быть достаточно большим. Например, если у вас сложный поиск по подстроке, по датам, по категориям, вы можете весь его уложить в класс с десятью-пятнадцатью полями. Поскольку все поля это примитивы, то класс сериализуем и его можно использовать на уровне представления как есть.